# how to write a loop in python from txt file that compares the last timestamp to the current one while reading it line by line?

Tags: python, split, string-comparison, txt

I am very new to python programming and I am trying to write a program using a raw text file that I have. I want to write a loop that reads the file line by line and compares the last timestamp to the current one in my file so that gives me the line number where to split the file. Then I want to write another loop that writes lines to a new file based on those line numbers.

I  am only able to get to write the lines by lines but any other codes that I put after does not work. I really hope someone can assist me with this.

Below is the snap shot of a few lines from start and end of the data. The last column with `"**"` is the time stamp. The data is rather large.

```
-1.75, 1.08, 10.35, -0.10, -0.01, -0.01, 23.19, *488*
-1.75, 1.12, 10.39, -0.10, -0.01, -0.01, 23.20, *521*

9.65, -1.31, -1.95, -0.11, -0.06, -0.02, 22.05, *15339436*
```

**This is how far I am able to go:**

```
import pandas as pd

count = 0
start_time = 0
split_numbers = []

file=open('test-Copy.txt')
Lines = file.readlines()

for line in Lines:
count += 1
print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
```

**this is a sample of what it prints line by line**

```
Line1: -1.75, 1.08, 10.35, -0.10, -0.01, -0.01, 23.19, 488
Line2: -1.75, 1.12, 10.39, -0.10, -0.01, -0.01, 23.20, 521
Line3: -1.76, 1.07, 10.38, -0.11, -0.01, -0.01, 23.19, 553
```

I don't know what to write after to achieve the outcome I am looking for.

Any assistance is really appreciated.

Comment: Please, provide an example or clarification for "... compares the last timestamp to the current one in my file so that gives me the line number where to split the file". Show us what are "last timestamp", "current timestamp", and by what condition should we split the file.

Comment: thanks for the comment. the last time stamp is "15339495 " in Line338416:  9.56, -1.32, -1.97, -0.10, -0.00, -0.01, 22.05, 15339495 and the current time stamp is "488" in line 1 and they are in milliseconds. Data needs to be split into one file for each time the timestamp resets. script that compares the timestamp of one row to the timestamp of the previous row and if the new timestamp is lower than the old timestamp there is a reset, and the table should be split between those two rows.

Comment: Once It is split the data rows according to the timestamp resets, then I want to adjust the timestamps so that they start at 0 and are displayed in seconds rather than milliseconds.

Comment: I used this command to get the current time stamp  . I don't know if that helps                                                current_GMT = time.gmtime()
time_stamp = calendar.timegm(current_GMT)
print("Current timestamp:", time_stamp).                                                                 
Output : Current timestamp: 1665594237

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem without reading/writing stuff:

```
from typing import List, Tuple


def parse_lines(lines: List[str]) -> List[Tuple[str, float]]:
  """Parse lines
  """
  return [parse_line(line) for line in lines]


def parse_line(line: str) -> Tuple[str, float]:
  """Parse line: find timestamp and convert it to seconds
  """
  ind = line.rfind(', ')
  return (line[:ind], float(line[ind + 2:]) / 1000)


def format_lines(lines: List[Tuple[str, float]]) -> List[str]:
  """Format lines
  """
  return [format_line(line) for line in lines]


def format_line(line: Tuple[str, float]) -> str:
  """Format line to the original format
  """
  return f"{line[0]}, {line[1]:.2f}"


def main() -> None:
  # TODO: read file as you did and store values in "lines"
  lines = [
    "-1.75, 1.08, 10.35, -0.10, -0.01, -0.01, 23.19, 488",
    "-1.75, 1.12, 10.39, -0.10, -0.01, -0.01, 23.20, 521",
    "-1.75, 1.12, 10.39, -0.10, -0.01, -0.01, 23.20, 133",
    "-1.75, 1.12, 10.39, -0.10, -0.01, -0.01, 23.20, 521",
    "-1.75, 1.12, 10.39, -0.10, -0.01, -0.01, 23.20, 1045",
    "9.65, -1.31, -1.95, -0.11, -0.06, -0.02, 22.05, 450"
  ]

  # Parse lines
  lines = parse_lines(lines)

  # Split data
  result = []
  start = 0

  for i in range(1, len(lines)):
    if lines[i][1] < lines[i - 1][1]:
      result.append(lines[start:i])
      start = i

  result.append(lines[start:])

  # Format result
  result = [format_lines(lines) for lines in result]

  # TODO: save data to separate files
  # TEMP: just to see results
  print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

P.S. In the comments sections OP said "... I want to adjust the timestamps so that they start at 0". I am not sure about the purpose of this transformation. So, I need more information to help here.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. So the result of the entire code was only resulted in change of milliseconds to seconds and only the def lines stated in the codes. Nothing further than that. I am not sure if it is the way the data in text file are collected. so here is the outcome of your codes:

Comment: [['-1.75, 1.08, 10.35, -0.10, -0.01, -0.01, 23.19, 0.49', '-1.75, 1.12, 10.39, -0.10, -0.01, -0.01, 23.20, 0.52'], ['-1.75, 1.12, 10.39, -0.10, -0.01, -0.01, 23.20, 0.13', '-1.75, 1.12, 10.39, -0.10, -0.01, -0.01, 23.20, 0.52', '-1.75, 1.12, 10.39, -0.10, -0.01, -0.01, 23.20, 1.04'], ['9.65, -1.31, -1.95, -0.11, -0.06, -0.02, 22.05, 0.45']]

Comment: Do you think if I change it to CSV file from start would it be better in terms of coding?

Comment: In answer to your question about the start at"0", what I am trying to do is once I am able to split the data rows according to the timestamp resets , adjust the timestamps so that they start at 0 . This way I will be able to use the timestamp as the x-axis when plotting graphs. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: There was not only ms to s transofmation, but also splitting by the rule you mentioned. If it is not result you desire, than, please, provide us an example result.

Comment: When you use some known data formats, you can easily find already written tools to manipule it. Actually, format of the file you showed us is CSV. So, here you talk about changing file to the proper extension from ".txt" to ".csv" and further using of some instruments (`pandas` for example). It's totaly up to your tastes and needs.

Comment: If I got you correctly, when we see the current line timestamp `135` and the next line timestamp `45` - it means clock was reset between this two moments. So, in fact, it means that `45` milliseconds have passed from 0.

Comment: To clear the confusion the original post is "txt" file, not sure if you are able to see it above in the coding section. Now I changed it to CSV. I think it is easier to find the already written tools for CSV. I know it may not make that much of sense to a newbie like me. LOL . Below is the example result with adding your above codes. nothing just a backbone of how the data looks like when I call it.

Comment: Import pandas as pd

# reading given csv file 
# and creating dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("k-test-Copy.txt",header = None)

# adding column headings
df.columns = ['a x', 'a y', 'ac z', 'g x', 'g y', 'g z', 'tp', 'timestamp millisecond']
  
# store dataframe into csv file
df.to_csv('k-test-Copy.csv', index = None)

print(df)  


# adding column headings
df.columns = ['a x', 'a y', 'ac z', 'g x', 'g y', 'g z', 't p', 'timestamp millisecond']
  
# store dataframe into csv file
df.to_csv('k-test-Copy.csv', index = None)

print(df)

Comment: Unfortunately, on this comment section it does not allow post the example properly so I can show you what the result of the above codes are. Can you tell me how to post the codes here?

Comment: and yes, you are correct about your statement" when we see the current line timestamp 135 and the next line timestamp 45 - it means clock was reset between this two moments. So, in fact, it means that 45 milliseconds have passed from 0. "